# Visual Studio 2010: Data Sources window in ASP.Net project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datasource

I'm trying to add a Sharepoint site as a data source on a web project in VS2010; so I can generate the appropriate DAO code to interact with the site's data over REST. However, neither the data sources window, nor the Add Data Source Configuration Wizard seem to be available to an ASP.Net Web project. Is there something else I should be using instead? I know I could just create a class library project and add my Datasource there, or I could just manually make the REST requests; but I just want to see what my options are. Any constructive input greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: What happens when you go to View->Server Explorer from within VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I think you need to right click on "Web References" in your solution explorer and click "Add Web Reference..." You can then type in the URL of the site and it'll be added to your project just like any other library.